# knife solo で rsyncがFailed to launch commandで頻繁に失敗する

Tags: windows, chef, vagrant

`knife solo`で vagrant で構築した Ubuntu14.04 に設定をしているのですが半分ぐらいの確率で以下のエラーが出ます。

```
Uploading the kitchen...
ERROR: RuntimeError: Failed to launch command ["rsync", "-rL", "--chmod=ugo=rwX", "--rsh=ssh vagrant@ubuntu", "--delete-after", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=tmp", "--exclude=.git", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.svn", "--exclude=.bzr", "/cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/dev/chef-trusty-ironsand/cookbooks/", ":~/chef-solo/cookbooks-3"]
```

`knife solo cook ubuntu`で上記のエラーが出た後に何も変更せずもう一度実行するとエラーにならなかったりするため原因が特定できずに困っています。

環境は Windows7, chef-dk 0.3.5, knife-solo 0.4.2, rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31 です。

また `~/.ssh/config` に `StrictHostKeyChecking no`の記述があることを確認してます。

単純に `ssh ubuntu`に接続を試みた時に失敗することはありません。

原因を特定したいのですがどのように調べたら良いでしょうか？

#### 追記

@helicac2001 さんのアドバイスに従い rsync をコマンドラインから実行してログを取得しようとしたのですが、10回ほど試してみましたが全てエラー無く正常に終了してしまい原因が特定できませんでした。

```
rsync -rL --log-file=rsync.log --chmod=ugo=rwX --rsh="ssh vagrant@ubuntu" --delete-after --exclude=revision-deploys --exclude=tmp --exclude=.git --exclude=.hg --exclude=.svn --exclude=.bzr /cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/dev/chef-trusty-ironsand/cookbooks/ :~/chef-solo/cookbooks-3
```

`knife solo`経由で呼び出す`rsync`の引数を変える方法はあるのでしょうか？

### `-VV`オプションを付けた場合のエラーログ

```
$ knife solo cook ubuntu -VV
Starting 'Run'
Running Chef on ubuntu...
Checking Chef version...
DEBUG: Initial command sudo chef-solo --version 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == "Chef:" {print $2}'
DEBUG: Initial command sudo -V
DEBUG: Running processed command sudo -V
DEBUG: sudo -V stdout: Sudo version 1.8.9p5
DEBUG: sudo -V stdout:

DEBUG: sudo -V stdout: Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.9p5
DEBUG: sudo -V stdout:

DEBUG: sudo -V stdout: Sudoers file grammar version 43
DEBUG: sudo -V stdout:

DEBUG: sudo -V stdout: Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.9p5
DEBUG: sudo -V stdout:

DEBUG: Running processed command sudo -E -p 'knife sudo password: ' chef-solo --version 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == "Chef:" {print $2}'
DEBUG: sudo -E -p 'knife sudo password: ' chef-solo --version 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == "Chef:" {print $2}' stdout: 11.8.2
DEBUG: sudo -E -p 'knife sudo password: ' chef-solo --version 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 == "Chef:" {print $2}' stdout:

DEBUG: Node config 'nodes/ubuntu.json' already exists
Installing Berkshelf cookbooks to 'cookbooks'...
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Using R (0.0.1)
Using apt (2.6.1)
Using build-essential (2.1.3)
Using chef_handler (1.1.6)
Using chocolatey (0.2.0)
Using dmg (2.2.2)
Using ffmpeg (0.4.3)
Using git (4.1.0)
Using java (1.29.0)
Using libvpx (1.0.1)
Using locale (1.0.2)
Using phantomjs (1.0.3)
Using rbenv (0.7.3) from git://github.com/sds/chef-rbenv.git (at install-gems-as-user)
Using ruby_build (0.8.0)
Using runit (1.5.12)
Using windows (1.36.1)
Using x264 (0.5.1)
Using yasm (1.0.2)
Using yum (3.5.2)
Using yum-epel (0.5.3)
Vendoring R (0.0.1) to cookbooks/R
Vendoring apt (2.6.1) to cookbooks/apt
Vendoring build-essential (2.1.3) to cookbooks/build-essential
Vendoring chef_handler (1.1.6) to cookbooks/chef_handler
Vendoring chocolatey (0.2.0) to cookbooks/chocolatey
Vendoring dmg (2.2.2) to cookbooks/dmg
Vendoring ffmpeg (0.4.3) to cookbooks/ffmpeg
Vendoring git (4.1.0) to cookbooks/git
Vendoring java (1.29.0) to cookbooks/java
Vendoring libvpx (1.0.1) to cookbooks/libvpx
Vendoring locale (1.0.2) to cookbooks/locale
Vendoring phantomjs (1.0.3) to cookbooks/phantomjs
Vendoring rbenv (0.7.3) to cookbooks/rbenv
Vendoring ruby_build (0.8.0) to cookbooks/ruby_build
Vendoring runit (1.5.12) to cookbooks/runit
Vendoring windows (1.36.1) to cookbooks/windows
Vendoring x264 (0.5.1) to cookbooks/x264
Vendoring yasm (1.0.2) to cookbooks/yasm
Vendoring yum (3.5.2) to cookbooks/yum
Vendoring yum-epel (0.5.3) to cookbooks/yum-epel
DEBUG: Cheffile not found
Uploading the kitchen...
DEBUG: Initial command ver
DEBUG: Running processed command ver
DEBUG: ver stdout: bash: ver: command not found
DEBUG: ver stdout:

DEBUG: Initial command mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/chef-solo
DEBUG: Running processed command mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/chef-solo
DEBUG: No chefignore file found at ./chefignore no files will be ignored
DEBUG: Initial command ver
DEBUG: Running processed command ver
DEBUG: ver stdout: bash: ver: command not found
DEBUG: ver stdout:

DEBUG: ["rsync", "-rL", "-v", "--chmod=ugo=rwX", "--rsh=ssh vagrant@ubuntu", "--delete-after", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=tmp", "--exclude=.gi
t", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.svn", "--exclude=.bzr", "/cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/resources/p
atch_cookbooks/", ":~/chef-solo/cookbooks-1"]
building file list ... done
chef-solo-search/.travis.yml
chef-solo-search/CHANGELOG
chef-solo-search/LICENSE
chef-solo-search/NOTICE
chef-solo-search/README.md
chef-solo-search/metadata.rb
chef-solo-search/libraries/search.rb
chef-solo-search/libraries/search/overrides.rb
chef-solo-search/libraries/search/parser.rb
chef-solo-search/libraries/vendor/chef/solr_query/lucene.treetop
chef-solo-search/libraries/vendor/chef/solr_query/lucene_nodes.rb
chef-solo-search/libraries/vendor/chef/solr_query/query_transform.rb
chef-solo-search/recipes/default.rb
chef-solo-search/tests/Gemfile
chef-solo-search/tests/test_data_bags.rb
chef-solo-search/tests/test_search.rb
chef-solo-search/tests/data/data_bags/node/alpha.json
chef-solo-search/tests/data/data_bags/node/beta.json
chef-solo-search/tests/data/data_bags/node/without_json_class.json
chef-solo-search/tests/data/data_bags/users/jerry.json
chef-solo-search/tests/data/data_bags/users/lea.json
chef-solo-search/tests/data/data_bags/users/mike.json
chef-solo-search/tests/data/data_bags/users/tom.json

sent 2,165 bytes  received 940 bytes  2,070.00 bytes/sec
total size is 47,483  speedup is 15.29
DEBUG: Initial command ver
DEBUG: Running processed command ver
DEBUG: ver stdout: bash: ver: command not found
DEBUG: ver stdout:

DEBUG: ["rsync", "-rL", "-v", "--chmod=ugo=rwX", "--rsh=ssh vagrant@ubuntu", "--delete-after", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=tmp", "--exclude=.gi
t", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.svn", "--exclude=.bzr", "/cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/dev/chef-trusty-ironsand/site-cookbooks/", ":~/chef-solo/cookbooks-2"]
building file list ... done
base/CHANGELOG.md
base/README.md
base/metadata.rb
base/files/default/id_rsa
base/files/default/known_hosts
base/recipes/default.rb
base/recipes/user.rb

sent 990 bytes  received 210 bytes  480.00 bytes/sec
total size is 5,007  speedup is 4.17
DEBUG: Initial command ver
DEBUG: Running processed command ver
DEBUG: ver stdout: bash: ver: command not found
DEBUG: ver stdout:

DEBUG: ["rsync", "-rL", "-v", "--chmod=ugo=rwX", "--rsh=ssh vagrant@ubuntu", "--delete-after", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=tmp", "--exclude=.gi
t", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.svn", "--exclude=.bzr", "/cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/dev/chef-trusty-ironsand/cookbooks/", ":~/chef-solo/cookbooks-3"]
building file list ... done
R/README.rdoc
R/metadata.json
R/recipes/default.rb
apt/CHANGELOG.md
apt/README.md
apt/metadata.json
apt/attributes/default.rb
apt/files/default/apt-proxy-v2.conf
apt/libraries/helpers.rb
apt/libraries/matchers.rb
apt/libraries/network.rb
apt/providers/preference.rb
apt/providers/repository.rb
apt/recipes/cacher-client.rb
apt/recipes/cacher-ng.rb
apt/recipes/default.rb
apt/recipes/unattended-upgrades.rb
apt/resources/preference.rb
apt/resources/repository.rb
apt/templates/debian-6.0/acng.conf.erb
apt/templates/default/01proxy.erb
apt/templates/default/20auto-upgrades.erb
apt/templates/default/50unattended-upgrades.erb
apt/templates/default/acng.conf.erb
apt/templates/default/unattended-upgrades.seed.erb
apt/templates/ubuntu-10.04/acng.conf.erb
build-essential/CHANGELOG.md
build-essential/README.md
build-essential/metadata.json
build-essential/attributes/default.rb
build-essential/libraries/matchers.rb
build-essential/libraries/timing.rb
build-essential/libraries/xcode_command_line_tools.rb
build-essential/recipes/_debian.rb
build-essential/recipes/_fedora.rb
build-essential/recipes/_freebsd.rb
build-essential/recipes/_mac_os_x.rb
build-essential/recipes/_omnios.rb
build-essential/recipes/_rhel.rb
build-essential/recipes/_smartos.rb
build-essential/recipes/_solaris2.rb
build-essential/recipes/_suse.rb
build-essential/recipes/default.rb
chef_handler/CHANGELOG.md
chef_handler/README.md
chef_handler/metadata.json
chef_handler/attributes/default.rb
chef_handler/files/default/handlers/README
chef_handler/libraries/matchers.rb
chef_handler/providers/default.rb
chef_handler/recipes/default.rb
chef_handler/recipes/json_file.rb
chef_handler/resources/default.rb
chocolatey/CHANGELOG.md
chocolatey/README.md
chocolatey/metadata.json
chocolatey/attributes/default.rb
chocolatey/libraries/chocolatey_helpers.rb
chocolatey/providers/default.rb
chocolatey/recipes/default.rb
chocolatey/resources/default.rb
dmg/CHANGELOG.md
dmg/README.md
dmg/metadata.json
dmg/attributes/default.rb
dmg/libraries/matchers.rb
dmg/providers/package.rb
dmg/recipes/default.rb
dmg/resources/package.rb
ffmpeg/.kitchen.yml
ffmpeg/.rubocop.yml
ffmpeg/CONTRIBUTING.md
ffmpeg/Gemfile
ffmpeg/Gemfile.lock
ffmpeg/README.md
ffmpeg/Rakefile
ffmpeg/TESTING.md
ffmpeg/Thorfile
ffmpeg/chefignore
ffmpeg/metadata.json
ffmpeg/attributes/default.rb
ffmpeg/libraries/helpers.rb
ffmpeg/recipes/default.rb
ffmpeg/recipes/package.rb
ffmpeg/recipes/source.rb
ffmpeg/templates/default/compiled_with_flags.erb
git/CHANGELOG.md
git/README.md
git/metadata.json
git/attributes/default.rb
git/libraries/matchers.rb
git/providers/config.rb
git/recipes/default.rb
git/recipes/server.rb
git/recipes/source.rb
git/recipes/windows.rb
git/resources/config.rb
git/templates/default/git-xinetd.d.erb
git/templates/default/sv-git-daemon-log-run.erb
git/templates/default/sv-git-daemon-run.erb
java/.gitignore
java/.kitchen.docker.yml
java/.kitchen.yml
java/Berksfile
java/Berksfile.lock
java/CHANGELOG.md
java/CONTRIBUTING.md
java/Gemfile
java/Gemfile.lock
java/ISSUES.md
java/LICENSE
java/README.md
java/TESTING.md
java/metadata.json
java/attributes/default.rb
java/libraries/helpers.rb
java/libraries/matchers.rb
java/providers/alternatives.rb
java/providers/ark.rb
java/recipes/default.rb
java/recipes/default_java_symlink.rb
java/recipes/ibm.rb
java/recipes/ibm_tar.rb
java/recipes/openjdk.rb
java/recipes/oracle.rb
java/recipes/oracle_i386.rb
java/recipes/oracle_rpm.rb
java/recipes/purge_packages.rb
java/recipes/set_attributes_from_version.rb
java/recipes/set_java_home.rb
java/recipes/windows.rb
java/resources/alternatives.rb
java/resources/ark.rb
java/templates/default/ibm_jdk.installer.properties.erb
java/templates/default/oracle.jinfo.erb
libvpx/.kitchen.yml
libvpx/.rubocop.yml
libvpx/CONTRIBUTING.md
libvpx/Gemfile
libvpx/Gemfile.lock
libvpx/README.md
libvpx/Rakefile
libvpx/TESTING.md
libvpx/Thorfile
libvpx/chefignore
libvpx/metadata.json
libvpx/attributes/default.rb
libvpx/libraries/helpers.rb
libvpx/recipes/default.rb
libvpx/recipes/package.rb
libvpx/recipes/source.rb
libvpx/templates/default/compiled_with_flags.erb
locale/README.md
locale/metadata.json
locale/attributes/default.rb
locale/libraries/locale.rb
locale/recipes/default.rb
phantomjs/CHANGELOG.md
phantomjs/README.md
phantomjs/metadata.json
phantomjs/attributes/debian.rb
phantomjs/attributes/default.rb
phantomjs/attributes/gentoo.rb
phantomjs/attributes/rhel.rb
phantomjs/attributes/windows.rb
phantomjs/recipes/default.rb
phantomjs/recipes/package.rb
phantomjs/recipes/source.rb
phantomjs/recipes/structure.rb
rbenv/.gitignore
rbenv/.kitchen.yml
rbenv/.rspec
rbenv/.travis.yml
rbenv/Berksfile
rbenv/CHANGELOG.md
rbenv/Gemfile
rbenv/Guardfile
rbenv/README.md
rbenv/Rakefile
rbenv/metadata.json
rbenv/attributes/default.rb
rbenv/libraries/chef_provider_package_rbenvrubygems.rb
rbenv/libraries/chef_rbenv_mixin.rb
rbenv/libraries/chef_rbenv_recipe_helpers.rb
rbenv/libraries/chef_rbenv_script_helpers.rb
rbenv/libraries/matchers.rb
rbenv/providers/global.rb
rbenv/providers/plugin.rb
rbenv/providers/rehash.rb
rbenv/providers/ruby.rb
rbenv/providers/script.rb
rbenv/recipes/default.rb
rbenv/recipes/system.rb
rbenv/recipes/system_install.rb
rbenv/recipes/user.rb
rbenv/recipes/user_install.rb
rbenv/recipes/vagrant.rb
rbenv/resources/gem.rb
rbenv/resources/global.rb
rbenv/resources/plugin.rb
rbenv/resources/rehash.rb
rbenv/resources/ruby.rb
rbenv/resources/script.rb
rbenv/templates/default/rbenv.sh.erb
rbenv/test/integration/system_ruby/bats/global_ruby.bats
rbenv/test/integration/system_ruby/bats/installation.bats
rbenv/test/integration/system_ruby/bats/plugins.bats
rbenv/test/integration/system_ruby/bats/ruby_envvars.bats
rbenv/test/unit/spec_helper.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_global_defaults.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_global_full.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_plugin_defaults.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_plugin_full.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_rehash_defaults.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_rehash_full.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_script_defaults.rb
rbenv/test/unit/fixtures/recipes/rbenv_script_full.rb
rbenv/test/unit/providers/global_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/providers/plugin_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/providers/rehash_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/providers/script_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/resources/gem_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/resources/global_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/resources/plugin_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/resources/rehash_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/resources/ruby_spec.rb
rbenv/test/unit/resources/script_spec.rb
ruby_build/CHANGELOG.md
ruby_build/README.md
ruby_build/metadata.json
ruby_build/attributes/default.rb
ruby_build/libraries/ruby_build_recipe_helpers.rb
ruby_build/providers/ruby.rb
ruby_build/recipes/default.rb
ruby_build/resources/ruby.rb
runit/CHANGELOG.md
runit/README.md
runit/metadata.json
runit/attributes/default.rb
runit/files/default/runit-2.1.1.tar.gz
runit/files/default/runit.seed
runit/files/default/runsvdir
runit/files/ubuntu-6.10/runsvdir
runit/files/ubuntu-7.04/runsvdir
runit/files/ubuntu-7.10/runsvdir
runit/files/ubuntu-8.04/runsvdir
runit/libraries/default.rb
runit/libraries/matchers.rb
runit/libraries/provider_runit_service.rb
runit/libraries/resource_runit_service.rb
runit/recipes/default.rb
runit/templates/debian/init.d.erb
runit/templates/default/log-config.erb
runit/templates/gentoo/runit-start.sh.erb
windows/.gitignore
windows/.kitchen.yml
windows/Berksfile
windows/CHANGELOG.md
windows/CONTRIBUTING
windows/Gemfile
windows/LICENSE
windows/README.md
windows/TODO.md
windows/chefignore
windows/metadata.json
windows/attributes/default.rb
windows/files/default/handlers/windows_reboot_handler.rb
windows/libraries/feature_base.rb
windows/libraries/matchers.rb
windows/libraries/powershell_helper.rb
windows/libraries/powershell_out.rb
windows/libraries/registry_helper.rb
windows/libraries/version.rb
windows/libraries/windows_architecture_helper.rb
windows/libraries/windows_helper.rb
windows/libraries/windows_package.rb
windows/libraries/windows_privileged.rb
windows/libraries/wmi_helper.rb
windows/providers/auto_run.rb
windows/providers/batch.rb
windows/providers/feature_dism.rb
windows/providers/feature_powershell.rb
windows/providers/feature_servermanagercmd.rb
windows/providers/font.rb
windows/providers/pagefile.rb
windows/providers/path.rb
windows/providers/printer.rb
windows/providers/printer_port.rb
windows/providers/reboot.rb
windows/providers/registry.rb
windows/providers/shortcut.rb
windows/providers/task.rb
windows/providers/zipfile.rb
windows/recipes/default.rb
windows/recipes/reboot_handler.rb
windows/resources/auto_run.rb
windows/resources/batch.rb
windows/resources/feature.rb
windows/resources/font.rb
windows/resources/pagefile.rb
windows/resources/path.rb
windows/resources/printer.rb
windows/resources/printer_port.rb
windows/resources/reboot.rb
windows/resources/registry.rb
windows/resources/shortcut.rb
windows/resources/task.rb
windows/resources/zipfile.rb
x264/.kitchen.yml
x264/.rubocop.yml
x264/CONTRIBUTING.md
x264/Gemfile
x264/Gemfile.lock
x264/README.md
x264/Rakefile
x264/TESTING.md
x264/Thorfile
x264/chefignore
x264/metadata.json
x264/attributes/default.rb
x264/libraries/helpers.rb
x264/recipes/default.rb
x264/recipes/package.rb
x264/recipes/source.rb
x264/templates/default/compiled_with_flags.erb
yasm/.kitchen.yml
yasm/.rubocop.yml
yasm/CONTRIBUTING.md
yasm/Gemfile
yasm/Gemfile.lock
yasm/README.md
yasm/Rakefile
yasm/TESTING.md
yasm/Thorfile
yasm/chefignore
yasm/metadata.json
yasm/attributes/default.rb
yasm/libraries/helpers.rb
yasm/recipes/default.rb
yasm/recipes/package.rb
yasm/recipes/source.rb
yasm/templates/default/compiled_with_flags.erb
yum-epel/CHANGELOG.md
yum-epel/README.md
yum-epel/metadata.json
yum-epel/attributes/default.rb
yum-epel/attributes/epel-debuginfo.rb
yum-epel/attributes/epel-source.rb
yum-epel/attributes/epel-testing-debuginfo.rb
yum-epel/attributes/epel-testing-source.rb
yum-epel/attributes/epel-testing.rb
yum-epel/attributes/epel.rb
yum-epel/recipes/default.rb
yum/CHANGELOG.md
yum/README.md
yum/metadata.json
yum/attributes/main.rb
yum/libraries/matchers.rb
yum/providers/globalconfig.rb
yum/providers/repository.rb
yum/recipes/default.rb
yum/resources/globalconfig.rb
yum/resources/repository.rb
yum/templates/default/main.erb
yum/templates/default/repo.erb

sent 33,600 bytes  received 16,020 bytes  19,848.00 bytes/sec
total size is 915,238  speedup is 18.44
C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/tools.rb:4:in `system!': Failed to launch command ["rsync", "-rL", "-v", "--ch
mod=ugo=rwX", "--rsh=ssh vagrant@ubuntu", "--delete-after", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=tmp", "--exclude=.git", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.sv
n", "--exclude=.bzr", "/cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/dev/chef-trusty-ironsand/cookbooks/", ":~/chef-solo/cookbooks-3"] (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:272:in `rsync'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:229:in `upload'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:245:in `upload_to_provision_path'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:120:in `block in sync_kitchen'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:119:in `each'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:119:in `each_with_index'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:119:in `sync_kitchen'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:92:in `block in run'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:208:in `time'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:75:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:493:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:174:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:139:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife:44:in `load'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife:44:in `<main>'
```

#### 2015/01/13 追記

@ohga さんのアドバイスに従い`rsync`のデバッグをより詳細に出すようにし、`rsync`の返り値が`24`の場合も正常終了とするように書き換えを行った結果が以下です。

```
DEBUG: ["rsync", "-rL", "-vvv", "--chmod=ugo=rwX", "--rsh=ssh vagrant@ubuntu", "--delete-after", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=tmp", "--exclude=.git", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.svn", "--exclude=.bzr", "/cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/AppData/Local/Temp/solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99", ":~/chef-solo/solo.rb"]
opening connection using: ssh vagrant@ubuntu  rsync --server -vvvre.iLs --delete-after . "~/chef-solo/solo.rb"  (9 args)
building file list ...
[sender] make_file(solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99,*,0)
done
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=12400
[Receiver] add_rule(- revision-deploys)
[Receiver] add_rule(- tmp)
[Receiver] add_rule(- .git)
[Receiver] add_rule(- .hg)
[Receiver] add_rule(- .svn)
[Receiver] add_rule(- .bzr)
recv_file_name(solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99)
received 1 names
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=1 /home/vagrant/chef-solo/solo.rb
generator starting pid=12400
delta-transmission enabled
recv_generator(solo.rb,0)
generating and sending sums for 0
count=2 rem=111 blength=700 s2length=2 flength=811
send_files(0, /cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/AppData/Local/Temp/solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99)
send_files mapped /cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/AppData/Local/Temp/solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99 of size 811
calling match_sums /cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/AppData/Local/Temp/solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99
solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99
built hash table
hash search b=700 len=811
match at 0 last_match=0 j=0 len=700 n=0
match at 700 last_match=700 j=1 len=111 n=0
done hash search
sending file_sum
false_alarms=0 hash_hits=2 matches=2
sender finished /cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/AppData/Local/Temp/solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99
generate_files phase=1
send_files phase=1
recv_files(1) starting
recv_files(solo.rb)
recv mapped solo.rb of size 811
got file_sum
renaming .solo.rb.Za4bb5 to solo.rb
recv_files phase=1
generate_files phase=2
send_files phase=2
send files finished
total: matches=2  hash_hits=2  false_alarms=0 data=0
recv_files phase=2
recv_files finished
generate_files phase=3
generate_files finished

sent 184 bytes  received 847 bytes  687.33 bytes/sec
total size is 811  speedup is 0.79
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1183): about to call exit(0)
C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/tools.rb:10:in `system!': Failed to launch command (100) ["rsync", "-rL", "-vvv", "--chmod=ugo=rwX", "--rsh=ssh vagrant@ubuntu", "--delete-after", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=tmp", "--exclude=.git", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.svn", "--exclude=.bzr", "/cygdrive/C/Users/ironsand/AppData/Local/Temp/solo.rb20150115-1272-134yk99", ":~/chef-solo/solo.rb"] (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:273:in `rsync'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:230:in `upload'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:255:in `write'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:226:in `generate_solorb'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:93:in `block in run'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:209:in `time'
        from C:/Users/ironsand/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb:75:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:493:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:174:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:139:in `run'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife:44:in `load'
        from C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife:44:in `<main>'
```

非常に長いので最後付近のみ貼り付けていますが、`rsync`が`code=0`で正常終了しているのに何故か`100`が返っているとなってしまっています。

rsyncのドキュメントには30までしかありませんし、どこからこの`100`は来てるのでしょうか？

#### 2015/01/15 追記

同様のエラーが出た人向けの情報として`knife-solo`のIssueに登録しておきました。
https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/issues/420

Comment: rsync コマンドに --log-file=rsync.log などを付けて実行ログを確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: `knife-solo`から呼び出すときに`rsync`のオプションを追加することはできるんでしょうか？ コマンドラインから同様のrsyncを実行してもエラーが出ずに正常終了してしまうようです。詳しくは本文に追加しておきます。

Comment: knife/solo_cook.rb を見ますと、rsync に与えるオプションを追加できる様なのですが、実際の環境がないので確認が取れません。ただ、knife solo のオプションに "-VV" オプション(詳細なログを出力)がありますので、knife solo cook -VV ... などとして確認ができるかと思います。

Comment: Windows側の rsync を [cwRsync Free Edition](https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/cwrsync-free-edition) にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 関連するバグがなければ報告してはどうでしょうか
https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+

Comment: @heliac2001 cwRsyncを入れてみて5,6回試してみたところ全て正常終了しました。cygwinのrsyncの挙動が問題だったようです。

Comment: @YusukeAndo のちほど報告しておきます。

Comment: 追記してもらった `sent 922 bytes  received ...` の数行前あたりに、 `client_run waiting on %d\n` という出力あったりします？出てなければ、 `_exit_cleanup` した後に子プロセス(たぶん ssh )の待合せをしてて、その終了コードが 100 なんかもです。

Comment: @ironsand 問題が解決して何よりです。ご存知かと思いますが、cwRsync には ssh コマンドも同梱されています。ですので、今回の問題の原因は cygwin の ssh なのかもしれません。

Comment: @ohga ないですね…。何か他にも私にはわからないヒントがあるかもしれないので念の為にもう一度、エラーを出して最後のあたりを貼っておきました。

Comment: @heliac2001 インストールを Chocolatey 経由で行ったのですが、その場合は`ssh`はインストールされないようです。なのでやはり`rsync`側との相性問題なのだと思います。

Answer (score 3):

追記して頂いたログを見るに、 `rsync` は成功しているのに、終了コードが `0` ではない、と判定してしまっているように見えます。

例えば、[rsync の終了コード](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html) では、処理中に転送元の変更を検知した時に出る `24 Partial transfer due to vanished source files` とかで悩んだ経験があるので、、

(目隠し状態で書いているので、バグがあるかもしれません、ごめんなさい。。)

```
diff -Nur a/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/tools.rb b/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/tools.rb
--- a/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/tools.rb  2014-06-06 16:13:54.000000000 +0900
+++ b/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/tools.rb  2015-01-13 13:53:14.000000000 +0900
@@ -1,7 +1,16 @@
 module KnifeSolo
   module Tools
     def system!(*command)
-      raise "Failed to launch command #{command}" unless system(*command)
+      if command[0] == 'rsync'
+        system(*command)
+        status = $?.exitstatus
+        if status != 0 && status != 24
+          raise "Failed to launch command (#{status}) #{command}"
+        end
+        
+      else                    
+        raise "Failed to launch command #{command}" unless system(*command)
+      end 
     end

     def windows_client?
```

みたいな感じで、 `rsync` コマンドが、終了コード `0` か `24` じゃない場合を失敗とする、的なコード変更をしてしまうと良いかもしれません。

ただ、 Windows の `rsync` の場合は、別の問題を抱えてい可能性はあるので、 `24` 以外の終了コードで失敗していて、納得いくものであれば、if 文でフォローしてみてください。(上記のコードでは終了コードを出力するようにしているつもりです。)

あとは、コードに手を入れるのが微妙であれば、 `rsync` コマンドそのものをラッピングしてしまうとか、 `--ignore-errors` を付けてしまうとか。(これは乱暴すぎるか。。)

それと、どうせコードをいじるなら、 rsync の debug 出力を、さらに上げてみるとなにかわかるかもしれません。

```
diff -Nur a/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb b/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb
--- a/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb  2014-06-06 16:13:54.000000000 +0900
+++ b/knife-solo-0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb  2015-01-13 14:11:31.000000000 +0900
@@ -184,7 +184,7 @@
       end

       def rsync_debug
-        '-v' if debug?
+        '-vvv' if debug?
       end

       # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798807/rsync-permission-denied-created-directories-have-no-permissions
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。両方の修正を行って試してみたところコマンドの返り値が`100`になってしまっているようです。詳しくは質問に追記しておきました。

Comment: if に追加すればとりあえずはしのげそうですが、全然、納得できんですね。。誰かが嘘をついているんですけど、ぱっと見、どのコードにも 100 とか 0x64 とかはないんですよね。。 vagrant あたりかなぁ。。

Comment: "Partial transfer due to vanished source files"ってちょっと変だな。もしかして、Vagrantのsynced_folderの中からrsyncのコマンドがやってるからかな？

Comment: @MatSchaffer `Partial transfer due to vanished source files` error doesn't happen that's only @ohga's speculation.

Answer (score 2):

```
DEBUG: ver stdout: bash: ver: command not found
```

という行が見えますので、設定でどこかに不用意な `ver` という記述が無いでしょうか？

Comment: 「送信先が Windows なら rsync のパラメータの 'C:' を '/cygdrive/C/' に置換したい」が為に、 問答無用で ssh にて  `ver` コマンドを叩いて、出力に 'Windows' があるか見てるっぽいです。 [ssh_command.rb#L198](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/blob/v0.4.2/lib/knife-solo/ssh_command.rb#L198) とか [solo_cook.rb#L177](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/blob/v0.4.2/lib/chef/knife/solo_cook.rb#L177)  とか。。

Comment: なるほどー。なんか綺麗なやり方とは思えませんが。。苦笑

Answer (score 1):

pemファイルの権限　600以外にしていると頻発しますよ